# Why is hungry singleton pattern thread-safe

Tags: java, design-patterns, thread-safety, singleton

Here is one of the singleton design pattern implementions: The Hungry implemention.

I've learned that this way can both create only one instance and keep the thread safe.

It's easy to understand that there is only one instance because instance is only created during the class loading.

But how come this can be thread-safe? Online docs say it's also because instance is created when class is being loaded. But I don't get the point,  how can this instance keep synchronized in  multi-threads situation? This is fuzzy to me. Can someone answer this, thank you in advance.

```
  public class Hunger {
        private static Hunger instance = new Hunger();

        private Hunger() {}    

        public static Hunger getInstance() {
            return instance; //When multi threads call this, there maybe a problem since only instance is provided.
        }
    }
```

Comment: The instance is not synchronized.

Comment: So is it thread-safe? I am confused.

Comment: The getInstance is

Comment: I guess you could say it is because there is no non-static method...

Comment: @doctorwhorm I think you're confused about thread-safety of (1) getting the object and (2) using the object.  Those are completely separate.  The Singleton pattern is about (1).  How the object manages (2) is a completely separate thing, about which Hungry/Lazy has nothing to say.

Comment: Thank you ,I may understand it. Didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy initialization will cause thread sync problem.
(Lazy init means that create singleton instance when you call createInstance() or getInstance() ).
But static Hunger instance's initialize time is faster than thread create time. 
It is not lazy init.

But it is not a complete synchronization.
Because it is just available at create instance time.
Maybe online docs said that is just for available at create singlton instance time.
So you must use thread lock object when you put any common resource members.

Comment: So is it thread-safe? I mean if there are 10 threads want to get the instance at the same time, who will get the only one instance with the above code? Will this cause a synchronization problem or just works fine?

Comment: If you just get a singleton instance then it will be thread safe. But you should be careful about that each 10 threads will access any singleton class's members, then it is not thread safe. So summary at 2 sentances. "Your singleton instance will thread safe" ,  "But it is not complete that if you access any members then it will not thread safe about that members"

Comment: And then you said 'who will get the only one instance with the above code?' But i can't understand it. Maybe it is not important thing that in each thread who will get singleton instance first.

Comment: p.s : You must release this singleton instance at main thread when another all threads are closed.

Answer (score 1):

to make sure you thread safely initialize your singleton, you could use a special kind of class, called enum. for example:

```
enum Hungry{
    INSTANCE;
    private static Random rd;

    static {
        rd = new Random();
        System.out.println("Initializing object...");
    }
    public Integer nextNum() {
        return new Random().nextInt(10);
    }

}

public class LazyEval {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Start...");

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("First call");
        System.out.println(Hungry.INSTANCE.nextNum());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Second Call");
        System.out.println(Hungry.INSTANCE.nextNum());

    }
}
```

you will get an output like this:

```
Start... 
First call 
Initializing object... 
6 
Second Call 0
```

This is because, when you first access INSTANCE, your JVM will initialize all fields on the static block. In this fashion, you can archive real time lazy initialization and avoid race conditions.

Comment: Like your way of using enum.

Comment: I'd love to, but my low reputation only allow me to accept, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with threads for a *Singleton* is making sure that you only initialize it once, and always provide the same object to everybody who asks. If you defer initialization to the 1st call:

```
public static Hunger getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Hunger();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

you can end up with two threads in the `if` block at the same time, calling the `new` twice, and bad things follow.

It's a separate question of how to synchronize the `Hunger` object itself; that's not about the *Singleton* pattern.

Comment: Your code is typically Lazy mode, and it's not thread-safe until you add synchronezed before the method(At least I think it is). But what I am curious about is the Hungry mode.

Comment: @doctorwhorm You already showed the Hungry mode above, where the object is created when the class is loaded. My example was to show you another way of creating a Singleton that is Lazy, not Hungry, and not thread safe. Isn't that what you were asking for?

Comment: Sorry, I may not express it properly. I just want to ask is Hungry mode thread-safe.

Comment: Hungry mode is thread safe to _get_ the object reference; it is up to that object whether any particular access to the objects methods or members is thread safe.